# The anointing at Bethany

Tags: john, luke, mark

In all four gospel accounts we can read that Jesus visited Simon the leper's house in Bethany, in Matthew 26:6-13. Beside Matthew in the three other accounts Mark 14:2-9, Luke 7:36-50 & John 11:2, John 12:1-7 it states that he was anointed.

> **Mark 14:8** She has done what she could; she has **anointed** (**μυρίζω murizó
> G3462**) My body beforehand for the burial.

> **Luke 7:46** You did not **anoint** (**ἀλείφω aleipho G218**) My head with oil, but she **anointed** (**ἀλείφω aleipho G218**) My feet with
> perfume.

> **John 11:2** And it was the Mary who **anointed** (**ἀλείφω aleipho G218**) the
> Lord with ointment, and wiped His

> **John 12:3** Mary then took a pound of very expensive perfume of pure
> nard, and **anointed** (**ἀλείφω aleipho G218**) the feet of Jesus and wiped His feet with her hair; and the house was filled with the fragrance of the perfume.

The other times in the New Testament the word Anointed has been translated is from this word (**χρίω chrio G5548**)

> **Luke 4:18** “The Spirit of the Lord is upon Me, Because He **anointed**
> (**χρίω chrio G5548**) Me to bring good news to the poor. He has sent Me
> to proclaim release to captives, And recovery of sight to the blind,
> To set free those who are oppressed,

> **Acts 4:27** For truly in this city there were gathered together against
> Your holy servant Jesus, whom You **anointed**(**χρίω chrio G5548**), both
> Herod and Pontius Pilate, along with the Gentiles and the peoples of
> Israel,

> **Acts 10:38** You know of Jesus of Nazareth, how God **anointed** (**χρίω chrio
> G5548**) Him with the Holy Spirit and with power, and how He went about
> doing good and healing all who were oppressed by the devil, for God
> was with Him.

> **2 Corinthians 1:21** Now He who establishes us with you in Christ and
> **anointed** (**χρίω chrio G5548**)  us is God,

> **Hebrews 1:9** You have loved righteousness and hated lawlessness;
> Therefore God, Your God, has **anointed** (**χρίω chrio G5548**) You With the
> oil of joy above Your companions.”

- What's the difference between the wording **μυρίζω** G3462 and **ἀλείφω** G218 then **χρίω** chrio G5548.
- In what context was he anointed?

Answer (score 3):

1. **μυρίζω** is a verb meaning to apply myrrh as ointment, especially for burial.  It occurs only in Mark 14:8.
2. **ἀλείφω** is a verb meaning to apply oil for the purpose of anointing festively or medicinally.  It occurs nine times in the NT: Matt 6:17, Mark 6:13, 16:1, Luke 7:38, 46, John 11:2, 12:3, James 5:14.
3. **ἔλαιον** is a noun meaning either oil generally or olive oil in particular.  It occurs 11 times in the NT: Matt 25:3, 4, 8, Mark 6:13, Luke 7:46, 10:34, 16:6, Heb 1:9, James 5:14, Rev 6:6, 18:13.
4. **χρίω** is a verb meaning to anoint or consecrate by anointing (hence "Christ" the anointed).  It occurs only five times in the NT: Luke 4:18, 27, Acts 10:38, 2 Cor 1:21, Heb 1:9.  The verb is always applied to Christ as the anointed.

Note that the meaning of #2 & #4 overlap somewhat.